# BizTalk server 2010 upgrade to 2013

Tags: sql-server, upgrade, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

I have a **BizTalk Server 2010 VM** I need to make 'cloud-ready' with smallest possible effort.

I'd like to do an **in-place upgrade to BizTalk Server 2013** (Standard Edition) -- anything older than that I believe would not be supported on an Azure VM, and anything newer than that would require upgrading the OS on the VM (from Window Server 2008 R2)

In theory, everything just works:

1. shutdown all processes,
2. run the `setup.exe`, and
3. start everything back up.

The only problem is that *in practice* **the upgrade fails** with this error

`Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__JobData__F1AC1A95114A936A'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.JobData'. The duplicate key value is (MessageBox_Message_Cleanup_BizTalkMsgBoxDb). HRESULT = 80040e2f`

How do I get around that?

Answer (score 0):

The *workaround* is to `truncate` the table `dbo.JobData` before the upgrade, because the upgrade *creates exactly the same rows* I had before.

But while this appears to be working, it feels a bit like a hack -- surely this cannot be the way the upgrade is supposed to work?

But is there a more official, documented way to remove that Job from the `JobData` table when doing the upgrade?